# Charge density inside dielectric with conductivity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, capacitance, gauss-law, dielectric

Consider the figures I and II

, they consist of similar circuits with identical batteries.  There are two different slabs connected in the circuit,  both are geometrically identical and have the same conductivity $\sigma_1$, but have different dielectric constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively, will yhe electric field inside these slabs be the same or different as a current runs through them?

[image]

My idea:
We know that $$J = \sigma E$$
But i think that this is considering that there are know polarisation effects by the material in which J exists. Now in linear homogeneous material, electric field gets reduced by a factor of k , we call this dielectric constant, so in this case also it should become $$J/ \sigma k$$
Hence we conclude that the electric fields must be different. I dont know if this is correct or not, can someone please verify or correct my concept